# Error: (node:17060) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension

Tags: javascript, node.js, import

I just started learning JavaScript by using Atom in order to create an online chart. Hence, I am quite unfamiliar with NPM, package.json and all that sort of things.

I want to import two modules by using the following code:

```
import * as am4core from "@amcharts/amcharts4/core";
import * as am4charts from "@amcharts/amcharts4/charts";
```

Which gives the following error message:

```
(node:17060) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
C:\Users\PF1VMKH9_ADM\Documents\herverkaveling\test:4
import * as am4core from "@amcharts/amcharts4/core";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1001:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1049:27)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Object.newLoader [as .js] (C:\Users\PF1VMKH9_ADM\.atom\packages\script\node_modules\pirates\lib\index.js:104:7)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\PF1VMKH9_ADM\.atom\packages\script\node_modules\@babel\node\lib\_babel-node.js:176:21)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
[Finished in 0.522s]
```

I added "type": "module" to the package.json file but it did not solve the issue:

```
{
  "name": "packages",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type":"module",
  "dependencies": {
    "typescript": "^4.4.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you want to use `import`, use` webpack`